# Redireccionamientos DNS con Bind9

Tags: dns

Mi Dominio de la red es hlg.cu, lo que quiero hacer es que el DNS principal 192.168.16.1, al hacerle alguna peticion a cualquier otra pagina o sitio q no pertenesca a la red q me redireccione a la pagina de Inicio que es la 192.168.16.102, asi tengo configurado el DNS, esa redireccion que la haga tanto en https con http, he probado varios metodos pero no me funciona, asi tengo configurado el dns:

$ORIGIN .
$TTL 604800 ; 1 week
hlg.cu  IN  SOA hlg.cu. root.hlg.cu. (
            201610557
            604800
            86400
            2419200
            604800 )
            NS  ns.hlg.cu.
            A   192.168.16.1

$ORIGIN _tcp.dc._msdcs.hlg.cu.
$ORIGIN hlg.cu.
_ntp_udp        SRV 0 0 123 ns
$ORIGIN _tcp.hlg.cu.

$ORIGIN hlg.cu.
chat            A   192.168.16.111
jabber          A   192.168.16.108
noticias        A   192.168.16.114
ns              A   192.168.16.1
social          A   192.168.16.110
softwra         A   192.168.16.114
teamspeak       A   192.168.16.108
ventas          A   192.168.16.105
wow             A   192.168.16.250
www             A   192.168.16.102
xchat           A   192.168.16.111
xnova           A   192.168.16.109
travian         A   192.168.16.109
revolution      A   192.168.16.109
selfie          A   192.168.16.112
foro            A   192.168.16.113
juegos          A   192.168.16.105
mop             A   192.168.16.248

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No funcionan porque los DNS no redireccionan, su función es solo regresar cierta IP para un nombre o viceversa (ademas otras respuestas como textos, etc), esto lo hace por el protocolo DNS puerto 53. Todo esto antes de que tu computadora continúe con el proceso de la petición, ya sea HTTP, HTTPS o cualquier otro protocolo.

Por ende, el DNS no toma decisiones en base a si la respuesta es una IP interna o externa, el simplemente la regresa lo que tenga en su cache o si no la tiene la consulta al autoritativo.

Lo que podrías hacer es de alguna forma engañar a tu DNS para hacer un root falso y adicionar registros tipo A para las IPs locales con un wildcard.

La respuesta tomada de aquí: [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://serverfault.com/questions/396958/configure-dns-server-to-return-same-ip-for-all-domains)

En el `named.conf` establecer esta zona raiz falsa:

`zone "." {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.fakeroot";
};`

Después crear la zona falsa y adicionar los registros tipo A a tu IP destino.

`@ IN SOA ns.domain.com. hostmaster.domain.com. ( 1 3h 1h 1w 1d )
  IN NS <ip>
* IN A <ip>`